# Hadoop cluster configuration resource management

Tags: hadoop, resources, cluster-computing, cpu

I want to run my mapreduce program on a Hadoop cluster but I have a problem.

When I run the program, it seems that just master resource is using and slaves does not act. The CPU and RAM of the master was used but not slaves.

I have one master and 7 slaves.

master spec: 2 CPU core and 4 GB ram

slaves spec: 2 CPU core and 4 GB ram for each one.

When I run program master CPU usage is about 70% and ram usage about 1.5GB. but slaves resources does not change.

Please help me. It's very important for me. How should I configure my cluster to use resource more optimized.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: at first check that all nodes are available, all services are run and can communicate. then try to run WordCount

Comment: my all nodes are running and everything is OK. I run my program and take screenshot from my YARN UI panel. you can see the screenshots from here
https://i.imgsafe.org/e16cfb5fab.png
https://i.imgsafe.org/e16ce67c62.png
https://i.imgsafe.org/e16ce42104.png
https://i.imgsafe.org/e16c239a26.png
https://i.imgsafe.org/e16ca934c0.png

Comment: but slaves rest and no activity! there is cluster status screenshot
https://i.imgsafe.org/e183b0d6d5.png
https://i.imgsafe.org/e184055a51.png
https://i.imgsafe.org/e18425ccc0.png
https://i.imgsafe.org/e1843dd10c.png
https://i.imgsafe.org/e184306177.png
https://i.imgsafe.org/e18433975b.png
https://i.imgsafe.org/e1844b403c.png
https://i.imgsafe.org/e184465610.png

thanks in advance.

Comment: why are there ~5 instances of same processes like namenode, resourcemanager with different pids?

Comment: I solved the problem. thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

Please check the logs of the nodes or if possible paste here so that we can look at it.